# Webpack can't find a module 'jquery-form-styler'

Tags: javascript, webpack

In webpack's config file I set 'node_modules' and 'src/js/libs' as folders, where webpack should look for modules. 'jquery-form-styler' is installed via npm and lives in 'node_modules', but according to first error, webpack tries to find module in 'src/js/modules'. Why?

```
ERROR in ./src/js/modules/forms.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery-form-styler' in '/Users/ildar.meyker/Sites/html-taxnet/src/js/modules'
 @ ./src/js/modules/forms.js 5:0-28
 @ ./src/js/modules/app.js
 @ ./src/js/main.js
```

My webpack.config.js content:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        main: './src/js/main.js',
        metrics: './src/js/metrics.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js')
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/libs'), 'node_modules']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all",
            minSize: 0
        }
    }
};
```

My files structure:

```
/node_modules/
/src/
    js/
      libs/
      modules/
             app.js
             ...
             forms.js
             ...
      main.js
      metrics.js
```

forms.js starts as:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery.maskedinput';
import 'jquery-validation/jquery.validate';
import 'jquery-validation/additional-methods';
import 'jquery-form-styler';

...
```

Where 'jquery' and 'jquery-form-styler' are located in 'node_modules', while other modules in 'src/js/libs'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like webpack's reference to 'src/js/modules' wasn't due to it's attempt to find module in that folder. An error happened, because package.json in 'jquery-form-styles' had an incorrent main attribute. 'jquery.formstyler.min.js' instead of './dist/jquery.formstyler.min.js'.